# Axis2 with Spring inside AAR cannot find Spring libs

Tags: spring, hibernate, apache-axis, noclassdeffounderror, applicationcontext

I use Axis2 with Spring and Hibernate. All the Spring libs are located in the AAR/`lib` folder. But when starting the initializing method this is thrown:

```
...Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware
```

This is my Spring init service:

```
<service name="SpringInitService"
    class="services.implementations.SpringInitService">
    <parameter name="ServiceTCCL">composite</parameter>
    <parameter name="ServiceObjectSupplier">org.apache.axis2.extensions.spring.receivers.SpringAppContextAwareObjectSupplier
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="SpringBeanName">SpringInitService</parameter>
    <!-- <parameter name="load-on-startup">true</parameter> -->
    <operation name="getValue">
        <messageReceiver
            class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOutMessageReceiver" />
    </operation>
</service>
```

The startup method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public void startUp(ConfigurationContext ignore, AxisService service) {
    ClassLoader classLoader = service.getClassLoader();
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            new String[] { "classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml" }, false);
    applicationContext.setClassLoader(classLoader);
    applicationContext.refresh();
}
```

Note: I do not want to move the libs in the WEB-INF/lib

Please, help!

Comment: is Spring jar present in your classpath? It should be either included in your lib or the server lib

Comment: yes, all the libs are included in the AAR